# Low weight photography bag recomendation

Tags: camera-bag

Here's equipment I usually carry with me:

- 1dx
- 200mm f/2
- zeiss 100mm f/2
- 85mm f/1.2
- 35mm f/1.4

I do carry this stuff in LowerPro 5 lens bag. The bag is ok, but the accumulated weight is killing me. I'm not giving up my equipment, so I was looking around at other, lighter, bags, but they all seem to have the same weight in the specs, even expensive ones.

I'm looking for an ultralight photography bag, which would still protect the equipment. Can anyone recommend something in that category?

Comment: I have 6 camera bags, the weight difference between the smallest and largest is sufficiently small to make the weight of the bag pretty much negligible. I wish you luck, but I don't think you'll find it...

Comment: I've used several bags and I find that what makes or breaks my back is the large amount of stuff I cram into them. Though I would add that a sternum strap is essential to me. This keeps you from having to roll your shoulders forward all of the time which greatly changes things if you've never tried it with a heavy load.

Comment: Can you clarify: you're carrying all of this in a LowePro Lens Case 5 bag? (One of these: http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Lowepro-Lens-Case-5-Review.aspx) I'm guessing not because it would be just a little bigger than the 200 + body.

Comment: @DanWolfgang hehe. you can do it if you unmount the 200mm and put it into the upper department ). and it's not a lens case, but a 5-lens backpack

Comment: @ArsenZahray, so what backpack do you have, specifically? Do you have a link?

Comment: As others have said, the weight of the bag is inconsequential when you're carrying all that glass.  Perhaps a wide strap or a pad would help. http://www.amazon.com/Domke-725-310-FA-031-Office-Shoulder/dp/B00009R86L

Comment: Switch to mirrorless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that gear is very heavy, there is a lot of big glass. The difference in bag weights is not important. You'll save a negligible weight. Much more important is the comfort of a bag when it has all that gear in.

You could find a minimalist cut down bag but the lack of padding and adjustments will mean that it is very uncomfortable.

Better to get a bag designed to carry that heavy weight most comfortably.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest a quick experiment. Grab your bathroom or kitchen scale, and weigh each piece of equipment in your kit, including your bag. Stick all of the info in a spreadsheet and you can easily figure out what % of weight for the entire kit is your bag.

Then spend an hour or two visiting the web sites of bag manufacturers. Every bag's specs will have its weight. It won't take you long to see whether there are bags that'll save you any weight at all, much less significant weight.

To be honest, more important than absolute weight here is how comfortably you carry it. You probably ought to be looking into a good comfortable backpack or messenger bag with a good strap than a lighter bag. I don't think the weight is the problem, but if you're still using a shoulder bag with a stock strap (or, frankly, any shoulder bag with significant weight) that's your problem.